# How to Send Data from Ajax to Servlets

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

Servlet Code

```
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    String s =  request.getAttribute("stopName").toString();
    response.getWriter().write(s);
}
```

Ajax Code

```
function makeRequest(i) {
                 var stopName = document.getElementById('newStopName' + i).value;
                var Longitude = document.getElementById('newLongitude' + i).value;
                var Latitude = document.getElementById('newLatitude' + i).value;
                var Description = document.getElementById('newStopDesc' + i).value;

                document.getElementById('hidnewStopName' + i).value = stopName;
                document.getElementById('hidnewLongitude' + i).value = Longitude;
                document.getElementById('hidnewLatitude' + i).value = Latitude;
                document.getElementById('hidnewStopDesc' + i).value = Description;
                var xmlHttpRequest = getXMLHttpRequest();

                xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = getReadyStateHandler(xmlHttpRequest);
                xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", "Edit_Route", true);
                xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlHttpRequest.send("stopName="+encodeURIComponent(stopName));
            }

            /*
             * Returns a function that waits for the state change in XMLHttpRequest
             */
            function getReadyStateHandler(xmlHttpRequest) {

                // an anonymous function returned
                // it listens to the XMLHttpRequest instance
                return function() {
                    if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState === 4) {
                        if (xmlHttpRequest.status === 200) {
                            alert(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
                        } else {
                            alert("HTTP error " + xmlHttpRequest.status + ": " + xmlHttpRequest.statusText);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
```

i want send StopName and and again send to client using ajax please help me  using javascript not jquery.Actually i want send data and save it to database that s way i want test it

Comment: what you get from above code? any error?

Comment: Yes  HTTP error 500: Internal Server Error

Comment: first change you request.getAttribute to request.getParameter. getParameter is method used to get value of parameter from http request

Comment: I already do that error is Still

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be come because u have get parameter in wrong way.

```
String stopName =  request.getParameter("stopName") != null ? request.getParameter("stopName").toString() : "null value";
```

it will also handle the null condition.

try this code.

Comment: i get null value so how can i get Stopname from ajax

Comment: it will shown u null because stop name is not sended properly from ajax.
try to print the values before sending to server

Comment: also u can use post method instead of get,
bcz post is secure than get.

Comment: u can use the following jquery ajax.
$.ajax({
  url: "abc.java ? stopname =" + stopnamevalue,
  method : post
  
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});

Comment: yes i know that i m note implemented its on get method bt that i want only check this bcoz i have to send data jsp to servelt using ajax

Answer (score 0):

Is the servlet path correct in ajax code ?
I mean "/Edit_Route" not "Edit_Route"

Maybe the ajax can not found your servlet ,i think